# Built-in dependency injection with conventions

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

How to inject services without registering them?
I mean in the past some DI frameworks automatically registered `Service` for `IService`.

I'm in a situation where I have a dozen of services and basically registering every single one is a pain in the ass. so is this supported in asp.net core default DI framework?

Comment: Registering a dozen services is a pain? Really?

Comment: Well, I consider to withstand this pain and register it MANUALY. Many other developers WILL kill you when they stumble upon some reflection voodoo magic what registering everything they write.

Comment: @eocron Reflection can be super useful if you want to register from assemblies your not directly referencing in your project (plugins etc.) but I agree, do it manually.

Comment: In my experience such behavior indeed is useful in plugin-like systems, but not every forking time.

Comment: Yeah, MEF is a nicer way of doing it a lot of the time

Comment: @eocron it really makes startup.cs a huge class which is also ugly.

Comment: But at least it will not run anything unexpectedly, and it will be clear where it starts and where it is used. Instead of "find me and log some working time into trash bin"

Comment: @eocron why this convention might run something unexpectedly, there should be a priority between 'convention' registered type and 'manually' registered type when resolving the service by framework.

Comment: Well, if you working on project alone, don't bother. Just use reflection everywhere and you should be good. But don't show it to anyone. It will take time to explain why Bind operation is no longer works and why your assembly loading binding twice or not loading them at all.

Comment: If your startup class is huge, then split it up into smaller components.

Comment: @eocron .Net Core itself uses convention and auto registration extensively, for controllers/views etc, change the dozen classes to over a hundred (happens easily on a large app) and the need to register dependencies automatically is obviously a good idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The out-of-the-box DI doesn't support it and do not intend to do so. The built-in IoC Container is kept simple by design, to allow basic dependency injection which works for most cases.

If you want advanced features like registering by convention, assembly scanning or decorator support, you have to use 3rd party IoC container like Autofac, SimpleInjector, Castle Windsor.

Comment: Right. StructureMap supports this with one line. Autofaq can easily do it with a convention as well.

Answer (score 13):

I guess you like the way it works with Autofac:

```
var assembly = typeof(MyModule).Assembly;
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

But you don't want to switch to Autofac for some reasons (for example you want use extensions from external libraries to register their dependencies).
So my suggestion is to create some extensions that use reflection like these ones:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddSingletonsByConvention(this IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly, Func<Type, bool> interfacePredicate, Func<Type, bool> implementationPredicate)
{
    var interfaces = assembly.ExportedTypes
        .Where(x => x.IsInterface && interfacePredicate(x))
        .ToList();
    var implementations = assembly.ExportedTypes
        .Where(x => !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract && implementationPredicate(x))
        .ToList();
    foreach (var @interface in interfaces)
    {
        var implementation = implementations.FirstOrDefault(x => @interface.IsAssignableFrom(x));
        if (implementation == null) continue;
        services.AddSingleton(@interface, implementation);
    }
    return services;
}

public static IServiceCollection AddSingletonsByConvention(this IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly, Func<Type, bool> predicate)
    => services.AddSingletonsByConvention(assembly, predicate, predicate);
```

Now you can register all your services by simple code like this:

```
var assembly = typeof(MyType).Assembly;
services.AddSingletonsByConvention(assembly, x => x.Name.EndsWith("Service"));
```

Feel free to customize these extensions to match your needs.
For example you can fire an exception if you don't find implementations for some services if that will make you feel a bit safer.

Comment: It's 2023 and this code still works perfectly with no changes.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to mention the [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Scrutor/) which let's you use the ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection but adds a fluent interface on top of it to allow for convention-based configuration.

Read this [article](https://kristian.hellang.com/introducing-scrutor/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @cherepets' answer, if you would like to:

- register transient services by convention
- search in different assemblies for interface and implementation
- only look at those that begin with a particular namespace (eg, company name or app name)
- only look at implementation names names that "match" the interface name (eg, IMyEmail and MyEmail)
- throw an exception upon startup if any implementations are not found

You can use this function:

```
public void AddTransientsByConvention(IServiceCollection services, Assembly[] assemblies, Func<Type, bool> myPredicate)
{
    List<Type> interfaces = new List<Type>();
    List<Type> implementations = new List<Type>();

    foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
    {
        interfaces.AddRange(assembly.ExportedTypes.Where(x => x.IsInterface && myPredicate(x)));
        implementations.AddRange(assembly.ExportedTypes.Where(x => !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract && myPredicate(x)));
    }

    foreach (var @interface in interfaces)
    {
        var implementation = implementations
            .FirstOrDefault(x => @interface.IsAssignableFrom(x) &&
                $"I{x.Name}" == @interface.Name );

        if (implementation == null)
            throw new Exception($"Couldn't find implementation for interface {@interface}");

        services.AddTransient(@interface, implementation);
    }
}
```

And then call it like this in your ConfigureServicescs:

```
var assemblyOne = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IMyRepository));
var assemblyTwo = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IMyBusinessLogic));
var assemblyThree = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

AddTransientsByConvention(services,
    new [] { assemblyOne, assemblyTwo , assemblyThree },
    x => x.Namespace.StartsWith("CompanyName"));
```