# How to Register Multiple Services, Multiple implementation in separate class and call it in ConfigureServices method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.1

Traditionally, we register multiple services, multiple interfaces under `ConfigureServices` method in the `Startup` class. This is feasible if we have five or ten registrations. But what if we have fifty or more such registrations?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  service.AddTransient<ISQLDB, SQLDB>();
  service.AddTransient<IEmployeeBusiness, EmployeeBusiness>();
  service.AddTransient<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();
  service.AddTransient<IEmployeeValidation, EmployeeValidation>();
  service.AddTransient<IDepartmentBusiness, DepartmentBusiness>();
  service.AddTransient<IDepartmentRepository, EmployeeRepository>();
  service.AddTransient<IDepartmentValidation, EmployeeValidation>();
  ...
  ...
  ...
  // some 50 or more
}
```

I want to move the registering part to another custom `InjectDependency` class and call this in `ConfigureServices` method like:

```
public class InjectDependency{
    public InjectDependency(IServiceCollection service)
    {
      service.AddTransient<ISQLDB, SQLDB>();
      service.AddTransient<IEmployeeBusiness, EmployeeBusiness>();
      service.AddTransient<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();
      service.AddTransient<IEmployeeValidation, EmployeeValidation>();
      service.AddTransient<IDepartmentBusiness, DepartmentBusiness>();
      service.AddTransient<IDepartmentRepository, EmployeeRepository>();
      service.AddTransient<IDepartmentValidation, EmployeeValidation>();
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What isn't working with your code? Since you're passing your `IServiceCollection` reference to your `InjectDependency` class, this should work just fine. Are you receiving an error? Are you just not sure how to call this? Note that since this is a stateless function, it may make more sense to treat it as a static method rather than a constructor.

Comment: Thanks. It worked by using extension methods

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work fine as is, though there are a couple of improvements you could make.

First, your `InjectDependency()` constructor is essentially stateless, so it would make more sense as a static method rather than a constructor. Second, to take that one step further, you could set it up as an *extension method* off of the `IServiceCollection` interface, which is a really common approach to this scenario:

```cs
public class ServiceCollectionExtensions {
  public static IServiceCollection AddBusinessLogic(this IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddTransient<ISQLDB, SQLDB>();
    services.AddTransient<IEmployeeBusiness, EmployeeBusiness>();
    services.AddTransient<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();
    …    
    return services;
  }
}
```

Then, in your `Startup` class, you'd simply call this like:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddBusinessLogic();
}
```

If you have that many implementations, however, you might also try to determine if there's a common pattern or convention you can use to dynamically register them. For example, in your sample data, a lot of your implementations share the same base identifier as the interface. If that pattern holds, it might be easier to write code that automates that. There's [a good example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47067187/3025856) on the question [Built-in dependency injection with conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180526/built-in-dependency-injection-with-conventions).

Comment: Thanks using extension method it worked.
Here is full implementation

Comment: I don't see any option to mark your response as Answer.
How do I mark the response as Answer?